# htaccess: deny direct access except specific domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
http://example.com/upload/aaa.jpg to
http://example.com/asset/example.com/aaa.jpg
```

~~

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^upload/(.*)$ asset/%1/$1 [L]
```

it works, but i wanna only allow ppl in example.com direct access to

http://example.com/asset/example.com/aaa.jpg

```
eg: http://aa.com only can access 
http://aa.com/asset/example.com/xxxx.jpg
```

how can i do that?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /asset/sss.ssss.com/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sss\.ssss\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

here is my solution

Comment: so you don't want people see it on your web page ?

Comment: i am afraid people will get in that path. i have to deny ppl to do it

Comment: no if you want to display image on your web page then you cannot hide the path

Comment: so you mean when i have to show that path image, i MUST allow ppl access it? i am using RewriteRule to get that path's image, so i wanna   disallow ppl direct access that path

Comment: yes because when you display the image on browser, browser first downloads the image from the server then it renders on the web page. so if you want to restrict from people then you also have to restrict it from your browser. Hence browser would not be able to display your image. Whenever an image is displayed on the browser then that image must be accessible by all people. Nobody can hide the client side codes or images in the world.